# Parts of the lines aren't split when using Split Line At Point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, line, splitting

The line shapefile is obtained from the Dissolve toolbox of all routes, so there is only one polyline in this shapefile. The point shapefile is already there. The [Split Line At Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003w000000) should allow me to get another shapefile which will be split according to the points. I notice that some of the lines are split, but some of them are not. The common feature for those lines don't get split is there is no turning line at that point, as shown below. This means the line is split perfectly when the point is the intersection, but for those points are just in the middle of a line, the split function will not work. Also, the points used to split the line are obtained from this line shapefile, so they are perfectly located along the line. This is a new question, which is not the same as the similar questions asked before since the problematic points are all the middle points along the line without intersecting with other lines. Any comments on this issue?

[image]

The following picture shows the problematic points where the line can't be split.
[image]
I am using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced License 10.3.1.

Comment: Hey, I don't think this is a duplicate question. As you can see, it has its different reason for the problem. Please remove the marked. Thanks.

Comment: "Why does Split Line At Points not split at every point encountered" sounds a lot like "Parts of the lines aren't split when using Split Line At Point" to me.  Even if two askers create their polyline and point feature classes in different ways when it comes to Split Line At Points they are just Lines and Points.

Comment: [My comment](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207237/parts-of-the-lines-arent-split-when-using-split-line-at-point#comment314828_207239) on this issue is `What happened when you tried "to make a copy of your data and run the Integrate tool first to ensure the lines and points are fully snapped before trying the Split Line at Points tool"? I think you may find that your points are only of near perfect alignment - Integrate should convert that to perfect alignment and enable the split.`

Answer (score 0):

I think the explanation and solution in a GeoNet thread entitled "[Split Line at Point not splitting where points are](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/103159)" may apply to your situation:

> What was the search radius setting that you used?  Not specifying a
>   radius would probably require essentially perfect alignment of your
>   points and lines, and nearly invisible imperfections in the alignment
>   would result in lines not splitting.  You may also want to make a copy
>   of your data and run the Integrate tool first to ensure the lines and
>   points are fully snapped before trying the Split Lina at Point tool.

Comment: I saw this information, but it doesn't solve my issue. The points used to split the line are obtained from this line, which means all the points here are of perfect alignment. As you can see, the problematic points within the red circle are all located at the place without intersecting with other links, which is not the same as those normal points in terms of successively splitting.

Comment: What happened when you tried "to make a copy of your data and run the Integrate tool first to ensure the lines and points are fully snapped before trying the Split Line at Points tool"?  I think you may find that your points are only of near perfect alignment - Integrate should convert that to perfect alignment and enable the split.

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking the points were created from the lines so they should be fine for the split. After I ran the Integrate, the problem got solved. Thanks.